# TFS Migration From Two Different Server to One New Server

Tags: tfs

I have currently two TFS server 1- tfs1 2- tfs2 and both are on tfs 2012 now what I want to migrate both tfs server on to one new tfs server which is on tfs2017 how can I migrate both old tfs server to new server. few databases are same on both old tfs server how can I migrate those to new?

I have tried to restore independently on new tfs 2017 server and its working fine now challenge is to merge both old server to new tfs server with all its collections.

Comment: Why tag [git]? Please don't spam unrelated tags.

Comment: Hi, I tried to move the project collection to another one and it works. Have you got a change to try it? If you meet any error during the process, you can share it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TFS does not support merge operations for team projects. However, you may try to:

1. Move the team project collection of the second server to the first one: [Move a project collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/move-project-collection?view=azure-devops-2022). Your servers should use the same TFS version.
2. Update your first TFS

In this case, you will get one TFS server that contains two project collections.